# Sanitizing the wort pot

Tags: sanitation, wort

Should i sanitize the pot that i will be using the prepare the wort before i use it? I will be using one of Mr. Beer hopped malt extracts and this is my first brew. The manual does not say anything about this. It just says boil the hopped malt extract with four cups of water.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boiling water (or wort in this case) will sanitize the pot and anything in the pot. No need to pre-sanitize.

By the way, make sure the pot is clean of any physical matter or the wort will pick up unexpected flavors from it.

Comment: Nothing on the "hot side" needs to be sanitized, just clean. Everything on the "cold side" has to be sanitized. The hot side is everything before and including the boiling of the wort. The cold side is when you cool your wort and everything that follows.